# How to connect wired Ethernet in terminal?

Tags: networking, server, terminal, ubuntu-18.04, ethernet

[image: Normal way]

As we all know, we can connect wired Ethernet by this way. When there is no Ubuntu desktop GUI, however, i have found no way to connect or disconnect that wired Ethernet.

Moreover, i am using campus network. That means what should i do is click "Turn Off" or "Turn On"，and i don't have to enter a broadband account and password.

So are there any terminal commands can realize the clicking of "Turn Off" or "Turn On" ?

Comment: As this is absolutely not programming related, you should ask this question on askubuntu or superuser

Comment: in fact, it's related to programming to some extent, for i' d like to write a script to realize the clicking to "Turn Off" and "Turn On" at specific time

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but using the ifconfig command

Assuming that this is your only port then it will have the tag of eth0

Which will mean the command is

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

Down switches the port off, if I want to turn it on the command is

```
 sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Handy guide for some Linux Terminal commands to do with ifconfig [https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/#:~:text=The%20“down”%20or%20“ifdown,is%20in%20an%20inactive%20state](https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cdown%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9Cifdown,is%20in%20an%20inactive%20state).

Comment: in my computer, the tag name is eno1. i use 'sudo ifconfig eno1 down', it works. however, 'sudo ifconfig eno1 up' fails, it enable the network, but i have to click 'turn on' manually. though i can make it connect automatically, my original intention is to connect it manually.

Comment: do you get a error when you run the up command or does it just silently fail?

Comment: it works, the Network Interface is disabled. when i use 'sudo ifconfig eno1 up' enable the network interface, i still have to click "turn on" to connect to wired ethernet